# Block must not be padded by blank lines. (padded-blocks)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to configure VS Code in order to avoid padding, via format line (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>)?

For instance the first line after the if statement is empty (padded):

```
if (a) {

    b()
}
```

The empty line after the if statement should be removed as following:

```
if (a) {
    b()
}
```

This should be done automatic by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.
Can the settings be configured accordingly in VS Code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Vscode itself does not provide that settings. You could use the the [Beautify extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify) with its `preserve_newlines` and `max_preserve_newlines` settings to achieve this behavior. An overview of all possible settings can be found [here](https://github.com/HookyQR/VSCodeBeautify/blob/master/Settings.md).
After you configured your settings you can create a custom shortcut in the `keybindings.json` to overwrite the default <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

```json
{
    "key": "shift+alt+f",
    "command": "HookyQR.beautify",
    "when": "editorFocus"
}
```

Comment: You should be able to customize the indentations with beautify, too.

Comment: Thanks! We are already using [JavaScript Standard Style] (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chenxsan.vscode-standardjs). Unfortunately, Beautify extension comes with indentations which are not conform with the JS standard. Maybe there is another way via JavaScript Standard Style?